# mb_send_mailでFromメールヘッダを追加すると、なりすましメールの可能性があります、と表示されてしまう

Tags: php, postfix

**mb_send_mailでFromメールヘッダを追加してYahoo!メールへメール送信**
Yahoo!メールで見ると、なりすましメールの可能性があります、と表示されました

・Q1.Fromメールヘッダを追加して、なりすましメールの可能性があります、と表示させないためには、どうすればよいですか？

・Q2.そもそも、Fromメールヘッダは、どういう用途で使用するものですか？

Comment: なりすましメールについては、yahooメールの仕様なのでヘルプ等を参考にしたほうがよいかもしれません。https://www.yahoo-help.jp/app/answers/detail/p/622/a_id/47937　その上でSPFやDKIMなどのドメイン認証についてわからないことがあれば質問したほうが良いかもしれません

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fromヘッダはメーラーでメールを開いた際に「差出人」や「送信元」として表示されるヘッダです。

デスクトップクライアントでもwebメールサービスでも大抵は変更できるようになっていて、なぜ変更できるかというと、
「普段とは別の環境からメールを送信するけど、相手先にはいつもと同じアドレスを表示したい/返事はいつものアドレスにもらいたい」場合があるからです。

Linuxのcrontabなどからメールを送ると、デフォルトでは「実行ユーザ@実行ホスト」になりますが、From欄を「普段人間が使っているアドレス」に設定しておくとお互いに便利です。

また、一部のwebメールサービスでは外部のメールを送受信できる機能があるので、この場合も任意にFrom欄を使い分けたい場合があります (Yahoo!メールにもFrom欄を変更する機能があります)。

- [Fromの送信者名、送信元メールアドレスの変更 | Yahoo!メール ヘルプ](https://www.yahoo-help.jp/app/answers/detail/p/622/a_id/80950/)
- [別のアドレスやエイリアスからメールを送信する | Gmail ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=ja)

ただしメールヘッダには本来の送信元やメールの配信経路もきちんと記録されているので、From欄と一致しない場合に「なりすましの可能性」として念のため警告しているわけです。

どうすれば警告されないかは送信している環境次第なので(From欄に設定したアドレスと、SMTPサーバのドメインが一致しない等)、この辺りの情報も提示してもらうとより詳しい回答が付くかもしれません。